# Image Resizing for different screens XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a long time but I haven't been able to solve it. How do I make an image appear smaller so it would fit the screen on a smaller device? When I have in on a larger device it fits fine but when switched to a smaller screen the images start to overlap.

[Example of images overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb8Vm.jpg)

I would really appreciate the help. Thank You!

Comment: are you use collectionview ?

Comment: it depends on how you layout those views. Provide some code or screen shots on how you building your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Use auto layout and set your Uiimageview aspect ratio to 1:1

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways. Some are mentioned below:

1. Using Auto layout
   connect every image to side of main view and set their widths and height ratio 1:1 , also set their width proportional to main view widht.
2. using stackviews and autolayout
   1st set images width proportional to main view width 
   then set their aspect ratio 1 : 1
   then add the columns to 2 vertical stack views and add both columns to horizontal stackview.
   set the left right and bottom constraint of final stackview
3. You can use auto resizing as well, but that is not totally reliable. 
   autoresizing is default behavior of view. In your case you have to set flexible width and height of each image
   [image: here]